# What kind of air conditioner system do I have?

Tags: heating, furnace, air-conditioning, natural-gas

I know this site says 'DIY', but if this question belongs somewhere else, let me know which site is appropriate for this question. Thank you.

At the beginning of this month, I had a Coleman air conditioner installed and connected to the bottom of the furnace through some foam-covered pipe or coil. Also, I am totally blind. So, although I can feel some of the things that are obvious, some of the stuff, like the boxes on the side of the wall, I am not familiar with. What are these boxes used for? Can you open or lift the cover on each of them?
Also, is my air conditioner considered a package system, where the compressor, condenser, and evaporator are all stationed outside, or is it a split system, where only the compressor and condenser are outside, and the evaporator is inside the furnace?
[Here's a video](https://www.icloud.com/attachment/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fcvws.icloud-content.com%2FB%2FAZ3b7VPDEC02tIfNhmy2rk7YF7SIAayDGZAIZWILoxgJ2iubc_9YY8Jp%2F%24%7Bf%7D%3Fo%3DAkCZIr2_MeW1PoeQxMHMq4KLyYLgUHaFjGIn7VQ2mwI2%26v%3D1%26x%3D3%26a%3DB0h4vqZUjmEWJYsrAHQkLey2dtoMA35cQwEACAHIAP8Yms1qA76zQg%26e%3D1527179376%26k%3D%24%7Buk%7D%26fl%3D%26r%3DCAD9C286-EC24-4372-A182-862A7B5F668E-1%26ckc%3Dcom.apple.largeattachment%26ckz%3DE31B66F9-26BC-4C3A-A1F5-02E41FA1F57A%26p%3D29%26s%3D2yOcWHxFoHt-HwkqjtsaAVpskwE&uk=1wSRnxEQVYRGlbkv5Pzlqw&f=IMG_0096.MOV&sz=200404518) I took. Let me know if it is clear enough. If not, I'll take another one, and I'll try to include another one of the furnace.

Comment: It's not reasonable to expect volunteers to download a 200MB video. Put it on YouTube or something.

Comment: The last time I tried uploading a YouTube video, I had some accessibility issues with it. I'll try again, but since my question has already been answered, I would probably not need to.

Comment: As a web accessibility specialist I can understand that, though I'm surprised that Google aren't on top of it at YouTube.

Comment: Actually, since I shot this with my iPhone, I tried to upload it directly, but it wouldn't let me select or change the category from the default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from the left, at the beginning of your video are:

1. Your Gas Meter
2. A weather-proof outdoor, In-Use, electrical outlet mounted on the wall. The plastic box has a cover with a clip on the bottom-right corner and opens upwards to allow access to 2 standard electrical outlets. This has nothing to do with your air conditioner.
3. The electrical disconnect for your air conditioner compressor, also mounted on the wall. This metal box has a clip at the bottom and also open upwards. There may be live electrical contacts inside so I wouldn't recommend opening it if you can't see what you're touching.
4. Your air conditioner's outdoor compressor and condenser unit. This is the large metal enclosure on the ground, vented all around, with a large fan on top under a circular wire screen.

Your air conditioner is a split system, with the compressor and condenser outside in the large box with the fan on top, and the evaporator inside with the furnace. They're linked together with the foam-covered pipes, which carry the refrigerant between the two halves of the system.

The end of your video just shows an empty space against the wall to the left of the gas meter below a window, with a ladder lying on the ground.

Comment: Thanks. About that second box with live electrical contacts. I saw, or noticed, a long cord connected to the inside of the wall trailing from the bottom. What is the purpose of that second box? Does that connect to the thermostat inside the house?

Comment: Also, why would the techs install an extra box that has two standard wall outlets? They were never there before until the air conditioner was installed. I thought it was some kind of a battery backup system.

Comment: The metal box on the wall supplies power to the compressor, so on the inside you should find a fat cable which leads to your house's main electrical panel.
There will be a much thinner cable, often attached to the foam-covered pipes, which leads form the compressor/condenser to the furnace and thermostat.

Comment: The standard electrical outlets might have been installed due to a code requirement - that I'm not sure about though.

Comment: I haven't watched the video but adding an outlet is fairly routine for pools, spas, hvac, etc. even if it isn't required. It's convenient for both you and future technicians who need to plug in refrigerant pumps or other tools.

Comment: I understand about tools and refrigerant pump, but I'm not sure what you mean by spas or HVAC. I thought the furnace and air conditioner make up the HVAC altogether, or are you referring to connecting an additional HVAC?

Comment: @HeavenlyHarmony -- the outlet is there so that the repairman who fixes your air conditioner has a place to plug in tools :)

Comment: @brhans -- you are correct that that outlet *is* a code requirement -- NEC 210.63's the cite BTW